# Chaos implies Nonlinearity?

Tags: chaos-theory, non-linear-systems

Why, for finite dimensions, is nonlinearity a precondition for chaos?

[This](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1152/e5645b17f9541c8c48d6581ff5d06b73135a.pdf) article (Linear Chaos? By Nathan S. Feldman) offers an example of an infinite dimensional chaotic map, which is linear. While it also suggests a hint (in section 2) about why finite dimensional linear maps cannot be chaotic, the reason is not immediately clear to me. Could one maybe relate nonlinearity to the fulfilment of the 3 criteria for chaos (mentioned in the paper)?

Moreover, could arguments made for a map/discrete dynamical system be naturally carried on to continuous dynamical systems/differential equations? I assume one would begin by looking at the flow function, but I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: The article explains exactly why this is true in Proposition 2.1.

Comment: This seems to be more of a pure math question than a physics question.  It'd probably make more sense at SE.Math.

Comment: I wasn't able to see how exactly it does, hence the question. Additionally, the answer proposed is for a map. How does one extend it to a continuous dynamical system?

Comment: @Primo-uomo Does that mean that you don't understand the proof, or that you don't understand how the proposition itself leads to the conclusion that finite-dimensional linear maps cannot be chaotic?

Comment: @probably_someone I understand the proof in itself. I have difficulties with the latter. Additionally, I would like to understand how this translates to the case of continuous dynamical systems.

Comment: Public service announcement: the user who flagged this comment discussion as "rude or abusive" should [read these guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032/280545).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does.

My take is that, without nonlinearity, folding is missing.

One of the main mechanisms behind classical chaos is the so-called [*stretch and fold*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseshoe_map). It can be visualized as a blob of initial conditions being stretched and then folded over itself by the mapping: stretching leads to a divergence of close trajectories (the hallmark of chaos), while folding keeps them bounded (and dense).

A linear system may be able to produce stretching, but this alone corresponds to a trivial behavior, divergence. But, in the spaces we're considering, a linear system cannot produce folding:

> [none of the] orbits of a linear operator in finite dimensions [...] are dense in the space

*Why can't linear functions produce folding?*
- The reason is that folding means that an interval is mapped on itself twice, and that requires a non-monotonic function (and linear functions are monotonic), such as the [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map)'s [parabola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:LogisticCobwebChaos.gif).

Notice, though, that topology can provide the folding that a linear transformation alone can't, see, e.g., [Arnold's cat map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold%27s_cat_map), which is a linear map on a torus.

You ask about the condition 3, but we don't need to address it directly:

> if $f$ has a dense set of periodic points and is transitive, then $f$ must have sensitive dependence on initial conditions.
>   Hence only the first two conditions of the definition of chaos need to be verified when showing that a particular function $f$ is chaotic.

As for differential equations, any linear ODE, $\dot{\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$, [can be solved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation). More pictorially, the understanding of maps can be somewhat transfered to flows by means of [Poincaré maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_map) and, especially, [Poincaré recurrence plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_plot). See, e.g., Carroll's [A review of return maps for Rössler and the complex Lorenz](http://chaosbook.org/projects/Carroll/Carr12.pdf) or Crutchfield's [slides](http://csc.ucdavis.edu/~chaos/courses/ncaso/Lectures/Lecture3Slides.pdf) from the lecture [Example Dynamical Systems](http://csc.ucdavis.edu/~chaos/courses/ncaso/Lectures/).

Comment: I understand the argument that chaos requires folding and since linear systems can't, then a nonlinear map is required. However, could you please elaborate on the inherent link between nonlinearity and folding, or point me to sources that do so? Because not all nonlinear systems are chaotic, it will be instructive to see exactly how nonlinearity leads to folding. Thanks!

Comment: @Primo-uomo, I added a paragraph addressing your question. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Two rather quick ways to solve the titular question are:

1. Finite-dimensional linear dynamical systems can be solved analytically.
   The solution is not chaotic.
2. Suppose a finite linear system exhibits a strong sensitivity to initial conditions, namely an arbitrarily small perturbation in the initial conditions blows up.
   As such systems are subject to the [superposition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle), we can decompose the solution into one for the original system and one for the perturbation.
   Applying the superposition principle again, a multiple of the perturbation solution must again be a solution.
   This however means that the dynamics is unbounded.